# Why .Net API function get stuck when executed in single pass in NI TestStand?

Tags: automation, teststand

I have automated a Windows desktop tool using ***System.Windows.Automation*** namespace in ***.NET Framework 4.5***. This desktop application is used as a configuration tool for an embedded hardware device.

My automation API is scripted in NI TestStand and integrate with other API scripts and is used to test the embedded hardware. During Single Pass of TestStand scripts, my automation API sometimes get stuck (3 in 10 times) on a missing dialogbox and as a result I lost all my testing report.

Current implementation of the function is such that if it doesn't get a control in specified number of retries, it return the status as failed and control back to calling function (and doesn't stuck). I have unit tested the function in visual studio in a loop of 200+ and also in testStand, but the function never get stuck. But when I run the signal pass, sometimes the same function get stuck in NI testStand.

How can I resolve this issue?